# MWE of zero-sum mask in the context of machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

Federated Learning seems to have a lot of potential, I understand it can be done using different techniques, e.g. functional encryption, etc. The simplest seems to be zero-sum masks. For TensorFlow this is e.g. described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89BGjQYA0uE) and [here](https://federated.withgoogle.com/).

I've tried to find an example of what this looks like, but there isn't much online, there is a [short discussion](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/25130/why-should-the-sum-of-masks-kernel-filter-in-image-processing-be-one) on the signal-processing SE, but it wasn't very illuminating. There is maybe something on [this Chegg](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/digital-image-processing-3rd-edition-chapter-3-problem-16p-solution-9780131687288), but paywall.

Would anyone have a MWE of doing aggregation using zero-sum masks?